# How do the specific bullet paths and hit boxes work?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have been playing a good amount of CS GO recently and I noticed that sometimes players get kills while twitching their crosshair to the side (no hacks, I checked). I think it has something to do with the hotboxes and bullet paths. How is the bullet path created in relation to the Crosshair? Also, why do people die to head shots when the bullet visibly does not hit the player?

Comment: I've seen things like this before, if you watch pro players and real good players they use this. But I've never understand how
Maybe the fact that you move your weapon faster then the crosshair moves or adjust can be the answer

Comment: A good example of this is when spectating pro matches like the Dreamhack summer when you apply X-ray view, you can see this clearly.

Comment: Could you maybe give a video example?

Comment: I wish you would've left this unanswered longer. I'd love to see some sample videos and more explanations on this.

Comment: @Carrie Accepting an answer doesn't prevent other answers from being posted—the accepted answer can be changed at any point too.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside I'm aware, but it does mark the question answered, making it less enticing (for those who are enticed by rep). In any case, I think it is an interesting question and _hope_ that there will be more insight :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all about the spray path/kickback of the gun.

The player hitbox is constant (unless you're moving of course), but when you fire any of the guns your next shot will be less accurate. The AK for example has a very accurate first shot, but then that accuracy is gone.

Players will adjust their aim based fire pattern based on the gun. Following the AK example, at close range, after the first two shots players will pull the gun down as the kickback and spray pattern of the gun starts pulling up.

Another example is the sawed-off shotgun. Standing some distance away with your crosshair on the target's head will rarely result in a headshot because of the spray of the bullets. However, aiming slightly below the collar bone on your left as you're looking at them (physical right) will result in one (at least in my experience).

A good way for you to see this yourself is to load up a game, stand and face the wall at some distance and hold down the fire button on any gun. You will see the spray pattern of the gun at that distance. The further away you are, the larger the spray area.

Here is a tutorial regarding the spray pattern in game: